# Installing Tomcat 7 in NetBeans 7.4 (beta)

Tags: macos, tomcat, installation, netbeans-7

Having a bit of a problem with installing Tomcat on Netbeans (OSX Mountain Lion)...

Tomcat install has gone fine and I can stop and start it from Terminal. Localhost:8080 displays without problems. However, I've added it to my server list in Netbeans (added an admin password with Manager-script permission in the Users.xml file) and although it shows up there are none of the start/stop/etc options on the drop down menu that should be there.

I've tried an uninstall/reinstall of Netbeans and I'm almost inclined to give in and try Eclipse instead (I'm a newbie so haven't decided on an IDE yet). Next step is to try the non-beta Netbeans but has anyone got any other ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: I am working with Netbeans 7.4 and 7.3 without any issue as you mension, so please try to use the latest stable (GA) version

Comment: As it turned out, I gave up on a web container and went for a full JEE compliant server instead (Glassfish). Thanks for the suggestion though :-)